# problems with excel showing producs when insterting measurments with multiple results

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

Hello i'm having problems with getting this to work. What i'm trying to do is when you insert a set of measurements i want excel to show the ( In this case  products) which are closest to those measurements.

***here is a picture:***
[image]

The result i'm trying to reach is when you type in the measurements you get product(s) and the manufacturer which are closest to those measurements.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Unfortunately, your question is quite vague and therefore difficult to answer. A picture will probably help a lot but also adding further information, e.g. explain what you have tried so far and what your expected result is.
Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/TvpFw heres a picture

Comment: The result i'm trying to reach is when you type in the measurements you get product(s) which are closest to those measurements.

Comment: I suggest you to also put screenshot of output and where you type measurements.

Comment: Currently nowhere, i'm still trying to figure out how exactly to do this.

Comment: @alexO, Output means your manual output. So that we can figure-out it by formula.

Comment: manual output? meaning? sorry i'm new to excel

Answer (score 0):

In essence, what you are after is an [`index+match`](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/) function. It will allow you to find a value in one list, given a corresponding variable. In this case, given a measurement, it will find a manufacturer and product combo in your list.

Your problem is that you will need to adapt your data to allow for this. For example, you need to decide whether you only want the closest match for measurements or if you need the closest match that is greater than the measurement you provide.
It is also possible that you'll need to split your measurement column into two different columns (unless all you need is the total area irrespective of individual lengths).

You could potentially avoid the index+match by using conditional formatting, but that would still require the data manipulation.

Given the information you provided, the answer will never be much more informative than this. But this should get you started and the following steps can be made easier with help from google.